# How do you make a button that marks the same word in two div in JS?

Tags: javascript

illustration of the execution of the button:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add mark tag in your Html code with JS. But mark tag works only in HTML5. It will be okay in new Browsers.

For example this is your html code:

```
<div>
    Word1 Word2 Word3 Word1
</div>

<div>
    Word1
</div>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click" onclick="" />
```

This is css code:

```
div { width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid black;float:left; }
```

And this is our javascript code:

```
var commonWord = 'Word1';
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    divs[0].innerHTML = divs[0].innerHTML.replace(commonWord, '<mark>' + commonWord + '</mark>');
    divs[1].innerHTML = divs[1].innerHTML.replace(commonWord, '<mark>' + commonWord + '</mark>');
});
```

But this JavaScript code marks only first words in divs
If you want to mark all words, you can use this:

```
    var commonWord = 'Word1';
    var button = document.getElementById('button');

    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        
        var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        divs[0].innerHTML = divs[0].innerHTML.replace(/Word1/g, '<mark>' + commonWord + '</mark>');
        divs[1].innerHTML = divs[1].innerHTML.replace(/Word1/g, '<mark>' + commonWord + '</mark>');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you -

```js
function myFunction() {
  var div = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  div[0].innerHTML += 'Hello';
  div[1].innerHTML += 'Hello';
}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  height:50px;
}
button {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span> world
</div>
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>

<button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Button </button>
```